# When I edit a post on Stack Overflow, who will review my edit?

Tags: discussion

When I edit a post on Stack Overflow, who will review my edit? Is it the post's author or someone else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score 5):

There is a privilege awarded at 2000 reputation to review the edits people make to others' posts. Three such users choose your question from a queue and mark it as Approve or Reject. If it's approved, it'll be visible to others except yourself(when, earlier, it was only visible to you). If not, it'll be discarded.

The author of the post can see that there's a suggested edit for his post. He can then approve/reject it in a single move, assuming it isn't already done by others.

Comment: @XieWilliam This is just a broad explanation - the linked page by JAL is more comprehensive.